# Switching between branches in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, version-control, branch

I'm still getting the hang of VS Code.
I want to make a react app using 2 different GET API URL endpoints but the exact same UI. In essence, I want to change just the base URLs between the 2.

I've tried creating a new branch in VS code to make 2 separate files but once I make edits in the master branch, the changes reflect in the new branch also.

Is there a way of making a different stand-alone branch from the VS code?

I've searched through the forums to no precise avail and I'm not that good at git. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your changes are being shown when you switch branch because you haven't commited your changes to a branch before switching.

Let's say you are on the `master` branch and make some changes. You can create a new branch `new-feature` and change your current working branch to `new-feature` bringing your existing changes across. This is useful because sometimes you will start to carry out some work before realising the scope is a bit too big and should be it's own branch.

If you want to keep the changes you have made on your current branch, you need to "stage" your changes with `git add your_filename.here` (or `git remove`). Once you have added and removed all changed files you want to keep on that branch, you need to `git commit` them. This is the step that finally adds the changes to the version history.

Now when you change to `new-feature` branch, your changes on `master` will not be there.

There are a number of GUI applications that make the git model more intuitive such as SourceTree, Github Desktop, and SmartGit

Comment: Thanks. It worked once I commited the work